# How do I view the author of a comment in a view block?

Tags: views, 8, nodes, comments

I want to create a view block to display information about the author of a comment.

So I created a comment block and added the fields I missed.
My problem, what contextual filter does it need to be added to show only the author of the comment and not all the authors ?

[image]

In response to 4K4 :

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't want to click on a link I don't know, but this seems to be a node and your contextual filter is for comments. Or is the view for /comment/[id] in case someone clicks on a single comment?

Comment: @4k4 Each user has a personal profile (profile module). I want to display next to each comment a block view with the user profile (username, publication date, photo, sex and age). How do you do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To place a view block next to each comment use the module:

[EVA: Entity Views Attachment](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva)

Create a new View for `user`, add an EVA display, connect it in ENTITY CONTENT SETTINGS to the Entity Type `comment`, the Bundle `default comment` and as Arguments provide the token for the user id `[comment:author:uid]`. Add a contextual filter for the User ID.

Now the EVA views block appears in the Comment Type and you can place it in Manage Display.

You can also use as Argument the comment id and connect it to the View you have in the question which is based on comments and has the author as relationship.

Comment: Thank you but how to configure the contextual filter ?

Comment: You mean the contextual filter for the User ID? You need to configure nothing, though you can configure *Display contents of "No results found"*, so that in case of an error, when EVA doesn't provide the correct argument, you see what is going on.

Comment: I have updated the question. I have 3 comments, the first one of "Samantha" and the other 2 of "Mathieu". On all the comments there is samantha.

Comment: This could be a caching issue, switch in the view Caching to None and try again.